# How can i choose a filter or an edge-detection technique that is suitable for a given computer-vision application?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to build a system to recognize sign language alphabet. I don't have experience working on computer vision because this is my first time. I don't know which filter i should use (sharping , smoothing , sharping then smoothing, smoothing then sharping Or even something else). Not just the filter choice but also other choices like:
1- Image Thresholding methods
2- edge detection techniques
..etc

Comment: Either use a ready-made library or take a true course in Computer Vision. It will be a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the computer vision world.

In my opinion, the easiest approach to implement is as follow.
The report of this method is at:  https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/871b/63ff97b76f4b9c3c9c780590947e1f0efa4d.pdf

## . Training phase

1. Prepare training images

[image: Training data : "D"]

2. Calculate training images' canny edge

## . Testing phase

3. Use webcame to capture hand's image
4. Extract captured image's canny Edge
5. Use kNN to detect nearest neighbor of captured image inside training images.

The 5. step is called recognition step. You could use something like SVM, etc

Of course, instead of canny edge you could use Deep learning to get better features. Which could lead to better accuracy, but that would be overkill for you now.
http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2016/pdfs/214_Report.pdf

Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways in which the problem can be solved. Two approach listed below

> 1. Using traditional image processing techniques: Do intensity based threshold, Edge detection and others etc.
> 2. use machine learning/ Deep learning:   Please find below reference for  ML/deep learning implementation.
>
> https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1710/1710.06836.pdf
>           https://cse.iitk.ac.in/users/cs365/2015/_submissions/vinsam/report.pdf

In my opinion/practice Deep learning methods generalize well compared to traditional approach, given lot of training data and compute.